# Fortran library for minimization or maximization of functions (optimization problem)

Tags: fortran

I'm looking for a library or individual package which provides convenient optimization subroutine for Fortran, any suggestions?

I'm testing the codes from Numerical Recipe, downhill simplex method and direction-set method, but the input-output interface is not convenient for chi-squared function, because we generally need to find the minimum of chi-squared function within a cube-like parameter space. Thus, I need a more convenient utility especially for least chi-squared problem.

Comment: Here's a big list of possibles for you to look through: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/software_l.html

Comment: Plus there is NLopt http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt

Comment: Great! NLopt is what I use.